# I try to create json object but i am not able to create

Tags: php, json

Here I have some function to read my table

```
<?php
 public function get_all_record($table, $fields = "*"){

            $sql = "SELECT $fields FROM $table";

            $result = $this->sqlordie($sql);

            $xx=0;
            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
              {
                $myrow[$xx] = $row;
                $xx++;
              }


             mysql_free_result($result);
             return $myrow;

        }
     private function sqlordie($sql) {

            $return_result = mysql_query($sql, $this->conn);
            if($return_result) {
                return $return_result;
            } else {
                $this->sql_error($sql);
            }
        }

        private function sql_error($sql) {
            echo mysql_error($this->conn).'<br>';
            die('error: '. $sql);
        }
?>
```

Below code I am calling the get_all_record function and return result I am convert into json object using json_encode

```
 <?php
 $myItem = get_all_record("mc_category","category_id,category_name,category_description");

    echo json_encode($myItem);
?>
```

I am getting output as below

```
[{"category_id":"2","category_name":"book","category_description":"all type of books"},{"category_id":"3","category_name":"book","category_description":"all type of books"},{"category_id":"4","category_name":"Phone","category_description":"All type of phones"},{"category_id":"5","category_name":"Phone","category_description":"All type of phones"}]
```

But I need JSON object as below

```
{ "aaData": [
    ["Trident","Internet Explorer 4.0","Win 95+","4","X"],
    ["Trident","Internet Explorer 5.0","Win 95+","5","C"],
    ["Trident","Internet Explorer 5.5","Win 95+","5.5","A"],
    ["Trident","Internet Explorer 6","Win 98+","6","A"],
    ["Trident","Internet Explorer 7","Win XP SP2+","7","A"]
] }
```

Could you please any one help to create above json object.

Comment: What happens instead? What goes wrong?

Comment: @Pekka Wrong is I am not getting proper json object

Comment: well, what are you getting instead? What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

json_encode gets an array with name/value pairs. You want just the values instead.
The best solution is to use

> mysql_fetch_row($result)

to get an numerical array, that gets converted to your preferred json format.

---

If you need the name/value pairs somewhere later you can still use

> mysql_fetch_assoc($result)

and create a second array this way:

> $mySoonToBeJsonData =
>   array_values($myrow);

this removes the names from the associative array

Comment: I update the code please check and I am not understand your solution

Comment: I need JSON object as below{ "aaData": [
    ["Trident","Internet Explorer 4.0","Win 95+","4","X"],
    ["Trident","Internet Explorer 5.0","Win 95+","5","C"],
    ["Trident","Internet Explorer 5.5","Win 95+","5.5","A"],
    ["Trident","Internet Explorer 6","Win 98+","6","A"],
    ["Trident","Internet Explorer 7","Win XP SP2+","7","A"]
] }

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following to encode instead:

```
echo json_encode($myItem, true);
```

Comment: I try the above code but still I am getting same issue I have updated the code please check the same